# How to calculate time for occurance of specific value in dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time, time-series, pandas-groupby

```
x['count']=x.groupby('a'['a'].transform('count')
```

**I have data with three columns starttime and endtime and a , with above line of code i can count frquency of points in column a but i also want to sum time for this value for example if in column 'a' value 60 occurs 100 times everytime value remain for 2 minutes or more how to calculate sum time duration for 100 times? if have any idea about this task please share here *
**here is my data** 
[image: input data]

[image: Here is my desired output]

above table is  my desired output

Comment: Please provide a small input sample and the corresponding output you want.

Comment: @smj i added my data and desired output